# VIM doesn't work with mouse in virtual terminals on all my machines except one.

Tags: vim, mouse

I have several computers with different versions of Ubuntu. GPM (general purpose mouse) is installed everywhere. Mouse is enabled in all vim instances. However, I cannot use mouse in vim when I am entering to virtual terminals (Ctrl + Alt + F1..F7) on all computers , except one. I compared settings, and I cannot see any difference. All vim instances are compiled with mouse_gpm . But, only one instance works fine.
Could someone suggest what else should I check?

Comment: Did you try to run `:set mouse=a` ? depending of your version, (vi for isntance), mouse is not set by default.
I suggest you to check `:help mouse` to get the best mouse configuration for vim, but keep in mind that shortcuts have been made to avoid the usage of the mouse in vim ;)

Comment: Oh! I was not clear saying   "Mouse is enabled in all vim instances." :)

Comment: I will add more comments. One one PC I am able to operate with GPM in vim in virtual terminals. On three other PC vim recognizes GPM, but I cannot operate with mouse when mouse=a . It's kind of malfunctioning, I enter the visual mode, and I am stuck there. It is consistent on three computers.  When I unset mouse=a I am able at least to use it as a mouse in an X window.